# Conditional Matching and Extraction involving 2 data tables

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyr

I have 2 data tables and their dput's are given below:

```
dput(x)
structure(list(site = c("A", "B", "C"), date = c("2018-05-06 00:00:05", 
"2018-05-06 12:00:00", "2018-05-06 17:00:00")), .Names = c("site", 
"date"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002570788>)


dput(y)
structure(list(sites = c("A", "A", "B"), vol = c(30, 40, 20), 
    date = structure(c(1525611600, 1525625640, 1525564805), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), pn = c("sp90", "sp70", "sp98")), .Names = c("sites", 
"vol", "date", "pn"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002570788>)
```

The resulting data table should be:

```
  site                date vol   pn
1:    A 2018-05-06 00:00:05  30 sp90
2:    A 2018-05-06 12:00:00  40 sp70
3:    B 2018-05-06 17:00:00  20 sp98
```

I need to check first if the site matches then check if x$date is smaller then y$date, pull vol and pn to x.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could something like this-

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[,date:=as.POSIXct(date)]
setDT(y)[,date:=as.POSIXct(date)]

x[, c("vol", "pn","site") := # Assign the below result to new columns
    x[y, # join
      .(vol, pn,site), # get the column you need
      on = .(site = sites, # join conditions
             date < date 
      ), 
      mult = "last"]]
```

Output-

```
> x
   site                date vol   pn
1:    A 2018-05-06 00:00:05  30 sp90
2:    A 2018-05-06 12:00:00  40 sp70
3:    B 2018-05-06 17:00:00  20 sp98
```

EDIT-

The dataset which you have provided in the question-

```
x = structure(list(site = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                   date = c("2018-05-06 00:00:05", "2018-05-06 12:00:00", "2018-05-06 17:00:00")),
                  .Names = c("site","date"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))


y= structure(list(sites = c("A", "A", "B"),
                  vol = c(30, 40, 20), 
                  date = structure(c(1525611600, 1525625640, 1525564805),
                  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
                  pn = c("sp90", "sp70", "sp98")),
                 .Names = c("sites", "vol", "date", "pn"),
                  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
                  row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

Comment: I have tried and for some reason it's giving an error "sites" not found.

Comment: I am using the same data which you have provided and it works for me.